# Type.GetProperties() working differently in debug and release mode

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a code that is calling `t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)`, where `t` is Type of a class `CTopic`. The class contains a property `Key` in a way as suggested by following code:

```
    public interface IKey
    {
        object Key { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IKey<T> : IKey
    {
        T Key { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class CBean<T> : IKey<T>
    {
        public abstract T Key { get; set; }
        object IKey.Key { get; set;}
    }

    public class CTopic : CBean<string>
    {
        public override string Key
        {
            get { return string.Empty; }
            set { string s = value; }
        }
    }
```

The `GetProperties` method is returning a `PropertyInfo` (among others) for "Key" property in `debug mode`. But same code returns two PropertyInfo[s] for "Key" property in `release mode`.

[image]

I tried to replicate it by creating a separate project and refer the assembly containing `CTopic` class and called `GetProperties` similarly but not able to replicate the odd situation in debug and release mode both.

Is there any project level setting or some other setting due to which it is occurring ?

Comment: Do you have any conditional attributes or #if in your project?

Comment: @nvoigt I didn't find any conditional attributes or #if, still if you look at the screenshot, the two `PropertyInfo` of `Key` property are both of type `string`, one from base class and one from child and obviously the one in child class is overriding the one in base, still why does it appear twice ? what coditional attributes or #if exist that could do this ?